# Issue with combining data from multiple Django apps into a single form option in admin back office

Tags: python, django, django-tenants

I'm a fairly novice developer, but I'm aiming to master Django by developing a multi-tenant SaaS application that lets users create their own online stores. I'm still at the beginning of the project, but I've already run into a problem that's blocking me.

My aim is to offer basic categories common to all users, while allowing them to create their own customized categories to classify their products. To achieve this, I've set up a multi-tenant architecture with Django-tenants, where each user has his own subdomain, store and categories.

However, I'm having trouble grouping shared and custom categories in the user administration interface form, just where they can add a product (and choose the related category). I want users to be able to choose the category of their products from a list that includes both, shared categories and their own custom categories.

I've tried several approaches, including the use of ManyToMany fields and custom widgets, but so far I haven't managed to get the desired result. Shared categories are not properly integrated into the category selection field, which limits the functionality of my application.

If you have any suggestions, ideas or pointers on how best to solve this problem and group shared and custom categories into a single form field, I would be extremely grateful.

Thank you very much for your help and advice.